# Find the distance to from point to the line

Tags: geometry

Here is the diagram

[image]

If we only know distance PA to line l1, distance PC to line l3, and angle alpha between l1 - l2, angle beta between l2 - l3, how to calculate PB from P to l2 the fastest?

Comment: In which form the lines are given?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Calling $|OP| = 2r$ we have

$$
2r\sin\phi = d_1\\
2r\sin(\alpha+\phi) = d_2\\
2r\sin(\beta+\alpha+\phi) = d_3
$$

three equations and three unknowns $\phi, r, d_2$

Answer (score 0):

Call $\gamma$ as the angle between $L_1$ and $OP$
$$\sin(\beta+\alpha+\gamma)=\frac{PC}{OP}\\
\sin\gamma=\frac{AP}{OP}\\
\gamma\implies\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{\csc (\alpha +\beta ) (PC-AP \cos (\alpha +\beta ))}{AP}\right)\\
OP\implies\csc (\alpha +\beta ) (PC-AP \cos (\alpha +\beta )) \sqrt{\frac{AP^2 \sin ^2(\alpha +\beta )}{(PC-AP \cos (\alpha +\beta ))^2}+1}$$
Since $\sin (\gamma+\alpha)=\frac{BP}{OP}$, then:
$$\bbox[10px,border: 1px black solid]{\therefore BP\implies OP\sin(\alpha+\gamma)\implies \csc (\alpha +\beta ) (AP \sin (\beta )+PC \sin (\alpha ))}$$